# How to delete one value from, and decrease the length of, a String array

Tags: java, arrays

I don't understand how to decrease the length of a `String` array. For example, with this code:

```
String[][] array = new String[5][2];

array[1][0] = "what";
array[2][0] = "is";
.....
.....
array[5][0] = "?";
```

How can I delete `array[5][0]` and get `array.length` to be 4, not 5?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove the array element from the end , you can also use [Arrays.copyOf()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28T%5B%5D,%20int%29) since jdk 1.6+

For example:

```
array = Arrays.copyOf(array, 4);
```

It just copy the original array 's first 4 elements to a new array , so it have the same effect as deleting the array[5]

If you want to remove an element from an specified index , you can use [ArrayUtils.remove()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang3/ArrayUtils.html#remove%28T%5B%5D,%20int%29) from Apache Commons Lang 3 to do it .

```
/**Remove the element at index 3**/
array =ArrayUtils.remove(array, 3);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot delete an item from an array.

But you can create a new array with smaller size and copy the content of the old array to the new one. Then, assign the value of the reference to the new array.

Consider using `java.util.List`.  It has a method `remove()`.

Answer (score 0):

Using arrays for such things is very time consuming. I can suggest these solutions:
1. Use one of the data structures provided by Java libraries. I'd go with HashMap since its structure allows mapping a value to a key (HashMap ) and it does the part of adding, finding and removing items. You can also use them for multi-level hashmaps if you need more than 2 columns (HashMap ) you can look that up.
2. Use a List or ArrayList structure. Make a list that contains arrays or a special structure you create to store your data.
3. (Not recommended) Go for the manual route. If you have a fixed-length array, you can shift the rows back to remove that row, and use an index to define the last row. If you have a dynamic-length array you'll need to reconstruct it each time you remove a row.